# Center text in circle before and after the spin

Tags: html, css

I found this and thought it was cool.  The problem is that I cannot seem to center the text in the circle either before or after it spins.  The current colors do not matter as I changed them just to be able to see the differences as I modified the code.  I apologize in advance for the length of the CSS code.  If anyone knows how to make it far shorter, I'm all ears so to speak.  I'm also hoping to make the words "clickable" after the spin, but have yet to figure that one out either

**HTML**

```
<ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="ca-icon">Home Page</span>
            <div class="ca-content">
                <h2 class="ca-main"></h2>
                <h3 class="ca-sub"></h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.ca-menu li{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    /*Circle Size*/
    border: 10px solid #E8FF02;
    /*border color before spin*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: #005B8E;
    /*background before spin*/
    margin-right: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 125px;
    /*circle vs square*/
    transition: all 400ms linear;
}

.ca-menu li:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.ca-menu li a{
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #BEFC00;
    /*text color before spin*/
    position:relative;
}

.ca-icon{
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #101254;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: center;
    padding-left: 45px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 900ms linear;
}

.ca-content{
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    width: 370px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 20px;
}

.ca-main{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-sub{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}

.ca-menu li:hover{
    background: #930016;
    border-color: #2BF802;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* colors after spin*/
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
    color: #0100B3;
    font-size: 20px;
/*text size after spin*/
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    display: none;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
    opacity: 8.0;
}

.ca-menu{
    padding: 100;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 250px;
    /*circle position from top*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix is to adjust the `line-height` of the words, `ca-icon`, to match the height of the parent, `.ca-menu li`, which has a height of `200px`.

```
.ca-icon{
    ...
    line-height: 200px;
    ...
}
```

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4zkvnnwz/11/) to see what this change does.

Comment: OMG!  So easy yet so hard, at least for me.  I'm glad that there are many here far smarter than I am.  I kept looking at padding, text, etc.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

-> when you enter large text in your spin than your design change check it.

-> please attached my following code and check and enter large text no change design.

-> same as your code but i was some change in css.

```css
.ca-menu li{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    /*Circle Size*/
    border: 10px solid #E8FF02;
    /*border color before spin*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background: #005B8E;
    /*background before spin*/
    margin-right: 10px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 125px;
    /*circle vs square*/
    transition: all 400ms linear;
    display: table;
}

.ca-menu li:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.ca-menu li a{
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #BEFC00;
    /*text color before spin*/
    position:relative;
}

.ca-icon{
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #101254;
    line-height: 27px;
    width: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 900ms linear;
}

.ca-content{
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    width: 370px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 20px;
}

.ca-main{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.ca-sub{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    transition: all 300ms linear; 
}

.ca-menu li:hover{
    background: #930016;
    border-color: #2BF802;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* colors after spin*/
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-icon{
    color: #0100B3;
    font-size: 20px;
/*text size after spin*/
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-main{
    display: none;
}

.ca-menu li:hover .ca-sub{
    opacity: 8.0;
}

.ca-menu{
    padding: 100;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 250px;
    /*circle position from top*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Stack</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body> 
         <ul class="ca-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span class="ca-icon">Home Page Home Page</span>
            <div class="ca-content">
                <h2 class="ca-main"></h2>
                <h3 class="ca-sub"></h3>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
    </body>
</html>
```